# how to upload bmp bitmap image in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, upload

I am writing a code in silverlight. I want to upload images on my silverlight application. Please help me how do I upload bitmap images and show them on interface. If I am wrong please sort it out.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight only natively supports .jpg and .png files. You will need a third party library to decode (or convert) bmp files for use by Silverlight.

You could potentially show them in a web browser control within Silverlight, but MS chose PNG and JPG for a reason, so why add complexity.I'd say convert them on the server after upload using one of many third party libraries available.

Comment: is there no workaround at all?I cannot use 3rd party libraries

Comment: There are workarounds (show them in HTML under a transparent Silverlight app, or in a browser control within Silverlight...) but why can't you use one of the free conversion libraries out there?

Comment: but you *do want functionality* :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more detail? Do you want to upload this to a directory on your site, store it within a DB or just retain it for the session and then dispose of the image?

There are a number of examples such as [Silverlight File Upload on codeplex](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/). or [File Uploader](http://silverlightuploader.codeplex.com/). If you are looking to upload to just a directory on your website you may want to [look at this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/file-upload-in-silverlight/) as well.

Aside from those starting points you need to provide some more detail as where you are having issues.